# check if an array of users match exist as entries in a linking table with a matching column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a Channels table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `channels` (
`ID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `creatorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateCreated` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `isRead` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `channels` (`ID`, `Name`, `creatorID`, `dateCreated`, `isRead`) VALUES
(1, 'chat', 260, 1456307705, 1),
(2, 'chat2', 36, 1456326568, 0),
(3, 'chat3', 260, 1456737864, 1);
```

I then have a userChannels table that lists all the members who have been invited into each channel. This is of the following format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userchannels` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channelID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `userchannels` (`ID`, `userID`, `channelID`) VALUES
(1, 36, 1),
(2, 260, 1),
(3, 36, 2),
(4, 1657, 2),
(5, 1657, 3),
(6, 260, 3);
```

I am creating a web service to check if the the users passed up in a webservice to be members in this channel already exist in a previous channel. So if they already exist, I will pass back the existing ChannelID and if not, I will create a new channel and add the entries.

So if I were to pass up the user ids of 36 and 260, I should not create a new channel and instead, I should pass back the channelID of 1 as per test data provided. But if I were to pass up 36, 260 and 1657, I would need to create a new entry in the channels' table as there is no current instance of all 3 users existing in one channel.

So I am wondering what is the best way to check if the users passed up already exist in a channel?

I think I may have to make use of group by in the userChannels table and build A Dynamic query?  But I'm really not sure how to implement this.

So far all I have is :

```
SELECT * FROM `userchannels` 
WHERE userID = ? or userid = ? group by channelID
```

This is returning unique channels. I guess I will need to build this query dynamically to keep adding userid = ? depending on the length of the array of users passed up in the web service. But I can't see where to go from here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How about `userID IN (`?

Comment: All the users should be in same channel or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `userchannels` 
WHERE userID in (user ids comma ceparated) group by channelID
HAVING count(userId)=<amount of user ids>
```

You can use IN to list all user IDs. If for a channel COUNT= amount of user ids it means all the users are added to the same channel.

Comment: this seems to be exactly what i need. The only question i have now is when running an explain on the query it is scanning the entire table. Is there any way to optimise this? I know it can be tricky when using 'in'. I currently do not have nay indexes on this table

Comment: Define a Primary Key for the userchannels table. It automatically adds index and IN will work based on the index.

Comment: Sorry I do have a primary key defined. I meant i didn't have any additional indexes apart from that. The primary key is ID and is auto incremented. This still scans the entire table however as per the explain

Comment: Than add the index on the userID column

Comment: I did that and the explain is still reporting back that it is scanning the entire table. Maybe this is because the table is so small at the minute that it is deeming it quicker to scan the table rather than use an index?